# IE11 places extra padding around list items

Tags: html, google-chrome, less, html-lists, internet-explorer-11

I have a strange issue with the way that Internet Explorer 11 handles uls that doesn't happen with any other browser.

Here is the picture of the ul in IE11:
[image]

And here is the picture of the ul in Chrome and other browsers:
[image]

```css
.iconImgBA {
  max-width: 2.4rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.listtweaksMA-ba2 {
  padding-left: 0;
  > li {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    &: last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    font-size:1.7rem;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="listtweaksMA-ba2">
    <li><img class="iconImgBA" align="center" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Modern Digital Marketing icon">Lead Generation</li>
    <li><img class="iconImgBA" align="center" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Modern Digital Marketing icon">Marketing Optimized Websites</li>
    <li><img class="iconImgBA" align="center" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Modern Digital Marketing icon">Social Media Marketing</li>
    <li><img class="iconImgBA" align="center" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Modern Digital Marketing icon">Content Marketing</li>
    <li><img class="iconImgBA" align="center" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Modern Digital Marketing icon">Search Engine Optimization</li>
</ul>
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong with this? If so what?

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to occur with the code in the demo. I did replace your local SVG image paths with placeholders, so maybe it's related to them. Did you inspect the document in IE? How tall are the images?

Comment: Considering that your list is centered in the screenshots, I'd assume that there's more CSS at play than what's shown here.

Comment: There is no more css at play. it is centered because of the li text-align center, so please don't downvote me for you not understanding my code

Comment: I just realized that the CSS you posted is LESS (or some other uncompiled variant). That was my mistake, but it complicates things. Please update your question with compiled CSS. And your unfounded snark isn't appreciated, especially after I spent 5 minutes looking into and improving your question for you. (You don't even know I downvoted, and questions get downvoted, not people. You won't get far if you take it personally.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem is the Internet Explorer 11 can't correctly interpret images with max-widths within lis. Changing max-width to width solves my problem. My hate for Internet Explorer has been renewed.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Do you have a reference to share?